# Win32 API: Create button with Aero effect

Tags: winapi, mingw, win32gui

I can create button with CreateWindow function like

```
    CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", "Button label", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 100, 25, parentWnd, ID, NULL, NULL);
```

It works perfect, but button has no glossy effects, font has no anti-aliasing.

I also compiled manifest:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="Win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0"
                        processorArchitecture="*" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Not sure, which token I must use, I got sample from some site. Then, I created resource list:

```
   CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "manifest.xml"
```

Compiled with:

```
   i686-w64-mingw32-windres -i resources.txt -OCOFF resources.res
```

And finally linked with `resources.res`, but with no any result.

When I created manifest and place it near my exe file - all works fine. But when I try to compile manifest into resources, I have no effect.

How to fix it? I prefer not to use any libs, especially large as Qt.

Comment: You don't link the .rc file, you link the .res file

Comment: Aero effect or do you have want your app to use new Windows XP/Vista/7 style theme? if yes then you will have to use create application manifest and initialize common controls

Comment: When I created manifest and placed it near my exe file all works fine. But when I try to compile manifest into resources, I have no effect.

Comment: You are doing that wrong. You didn't provide full details, so we can't tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: @bukkojot did you link to comctl32 and call InitCommonControls? Refer to this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
Make sure `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID` is defined as `1`

Or replace the manifest line with the following:

```
1 RT_MANIFEST "manifest.xml"
```

or

```
1 24 "manifest.xml"
```

Comment: @bukkojot: that means your dev environment is not defining the `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID` and/or `RT_MANIFEST` constants, thus you would end up creating a resource with an actual name of `"CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID"` instead of an ID of 1, and/or a resource type with an actual name of `"RT_MANIFEST"` instead of a type of 24.  Use a resource editor/viewer to verify

Comment: Wrong solution. Best to embed resource.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What do you mean? This is supposed to be "embedded resource" solution. It should work without a separate "MYAPPNAME.exe.manifest" file present in the distribution package. Unless OP says otherwise.

Comment: No, user has put that xml file alongside the exe

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Asker is already aware of non-embedded solution. See the original post where it says *"When I created manifest and place it near my exe file - all works fine. But when I try to compile manifest into resources, I have no effect"* The whole question is about embedded solution.

Comment: So can you explain what was was wrong and how your answer fixes it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think the only problem was that `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID` was not declared as `1`. I tried that on CodeBlock with MinGW, it works. Sometimes I add superstition to my post which don't really make sense. I deleted that part.